# error at \ifnum\luatexversion<68

Tags: pgfplots, errors, indexing

The following code (minimal example taken from [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41/2012/9/6/0-18))

```
\documentclass{article}

% Both of these are require to duplicate the problem
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produces the following error in imakeidx.sty (only in texlive 2012, not in 2011)

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                    <
l.48   \ifnum\luatexversion<
                        68
```

Any idea why this happens or can be solved is welcome.

Comment: If I change the order of the packages, it compiles with both LuaLaTeX and PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Unfortunately, a new version of `imakeidx` has reintroduced a malfunction caused by `pgfplots`.

Comment: As of today, version 1.2d of `imakeidx` is on the TeX Live servers; it should have corrected this issue and others due to bugs introduced in version 1.2 for which I apologize again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package `imakeidx` tests for `\directlua` before using `\luatexversion`:

```
\ifdefined\directlua
```

However after package `pgfplots` is loaded the command `\directlua` is defined with meaning `\relax`.
The problem is in the file `TDS:tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex`
and also
`TDS:tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex`,
`TDS:tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def`
are candidates, they contain:

```
\pgfutil@ifundefined{directlua}{%
```

The macro `\pgfutil@ifundefined` is defined in `TDS:tex/generic/pgf/pgfutil-common.tex`:

```
\long\def\pgfutil@ifundefined#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\def\pgfutil@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\pgfutil@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
```

`\csname` has the side effect that it defines undefined commands with the meaning of `\relax`. If `\pgfutil@ifundefined` (also the same with LaTeX's `\@ifundefined`) is called,
`\directlua` gets defined with meaning `\relax`. In `pgfplotsutil.code.tex` this happens outside of groups.

Package `imakeidx` tests for `\directlua` and finds it defined, because it uses eTeX's
`\ifdefined`.

In my opinion `pgfplots` shouldn't use `\pgfutil@ifundefined` for macros that should remain undefined. A better variant is (name with camel case):

```
\def\pgfutil@IfUndefined#1{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

Then `\csname` and the test is called inside group and the meaning of the tested
command remains unchanged after the group. The disadvantage is that `\pgfutil@IfUndefined` is not expandable. But this does not matter in the use case here and many other uses cases in the package. Other macros are also affected (`\@ifpackageloaded`, `\if@filesw`, …). See also package `ltxcmds` that defines `\ltx@ifundefined` and `ltx@IfUndefined` that support e-TeX if available.

Package `imakeidx` could do a more conservative testing to additionally check
the command to be tested for the meaning `\relax`.

Workaround to fix the issue for the OP:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\ifx\directlua\relax
  \let\directlua\UnDeFiNeD
\fi
\usepackage{imakeidx}
```

Defining `\luatexversion` has the severe risk, that other packages might be confused.

---

Further remark to `\pgfutil@ifundefined`: `\par` tokens break `\csname`, therefore `\long` does not make any sense here. A better location for `\long` would be `\pgfutil@firstoftwo` and `\pgfutil@secondoftwo`, then their arguments might contain `\par` tokens (depending on the semantics of these two macros).

Comment: So I can either load imakeidx after pgfplots or wait for imakeidx to be fixed ?

Comment: This problem for `imakeidx` had been corrected in May; unfortunately the new version was prepared based on version 1.1 instead of 1.1a; I apologize. The real bug, however, is in `pgfplots`.

Comment: The workaround works.

Comment: @Heiko thanks for the detailed analysis. I have fixed it in pgfplots using your IfUndefined macro; will become part of the next stable.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\luatexversion
\luatexversion=70
...
```

works if you are using `pdflatex`. However you should file a bug report to the author of `imakeidx`

Comment: Its now 10 years later - has this bug been solved in imakeidx and pgfplots?