# Undefined control sequence. \luatexversion with animate package

Tags: errors, miktex, animate, undefined

I am using pdflatex on a fresh (and current) MikTex 2.9 install with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
 Test
\end{document}
```

Pdflatex throws the error:

```
Package: pdfbase 2017/03/23 v0.14 driver independent access to low-level PDF fe
atures
\g_pbs_page_int=\count175

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \luatexversion 
                          <95
l.924 }
```

I have read the other posts containing the offending control sequence, especially [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/error-at-ifnum-luatexversion68) but the solutions offered there didn't help in my case.

This problem might have arisen with a recent MikTex update. I have now completely uninstalled, redownloaded, reinstalled and updates MikTex -- with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the `media9` package to version 0.81 as of 2017/07/24 which provides file `pdfbase.sty` loaded by pkg `animate`.

Quickfix until the next package update of MiKTeX: Put the current [↗`pdfbase.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/pdfbase.sty) into the working directory (directory with your document source).

A recent LaTeX3 kernel update made fixing `media9` (and other packages) necessary. Related:  [What does greedy \bool_if:n(TF) mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383071/what-does-greedy-bool-ifntf-mean)

Comment: The MikTex package manager only offers me version 0.80 by now. I will recheck within the next few days.

Comment: @David For a quickfix see edit.